# Extracting a atribute value of a XML header with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, header, substring, extract

I'm currently working on extracting data from a xml file with xpath to create later a SQL table with the data from the xml-file

my input looks like this

```
<Header dateOfExecution="2017-06-22 08:30:09" orderId="5000206348" status="O" messageId="1" type="REQ" serviceProviderId="SP010" externalId1="b0ddcfece1a345338f20902401fa1e71" />
```

for example i need to extract the name and value from "type" for my table

i know that i can extract the full thing with `//Header/@type` to get this : `'type=REQ'` but how can extract the name and the value of this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _name_ and _value_?

Comment: with name i mean i my example "type" and with value i mean "REQ"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `//Header/@type` doesn't return the whole string: `'type=REQ'` it returns only `'REG'` value,
You're probably using an online XPath tester that's why you're getting that result.

For the attribute name, you already have it? Why do you want to select it?
However, you can get the name by using the `name()` function.